# How to display the Google dot animation on an my app?

Tags: java, android

If you've used Google Assistant before, you've probably noticed that pretty animation when you're vocally dictating something. I would like to integrate a similar voice dictation feature in my application with the same animation. How should I go about it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what you have described, I think this library will meet your needs. https://github.com/zagum/SpeechRecognitionView

Here's a [preview](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zagum/SpeechRecognitionView/master/art/speechrecognitionview.gif) of what it does...

Download

Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.zagum:SpeechRecognitionView:1.2.2'
}
```

Simply add view to your layout:

```
<com.github.zagum.speechrecognitionview.RecognitionProgressView
    android:id="@+id/recognition_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Initialization:

```
 SpeechRecognizer speechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);
```

Init RecognitionProgressView:

```
RecognitionProgressView recognitionProgressView = (RecognitionProgressView) findViewById(R.id.recognition_view);
recognitionProgressView.setSpeechRecognizer(speechRecognizer);
recognitionProgressView.setRecognitionListener(new RecognitionListenerAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onResults(Bundle results) {
        showResults(results);
    }
});
```

Please be sure to check the library on Github for full setup process.